# Python 3.5 | Scraping data from website

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I want to scrape a specific part of the website [Kickstarter.com](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology?ref=discover_index)

I need the strings of the Project-title. The website is structured and every project has this line.

```html
<div class="Project-title">
```

My code looks like:

```html
#Loading Libraries
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#define URL for scraping
theurl = "https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=16&woe_id=23424829&sort=popularity&seed=2448324&page=1"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)

#Cooking the Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

#Scraping "Project Title" (project-title)
project_title = soup.find('h6', {'class': 'project-title'}).findChildren('a')
title = project_title[0].text
print (title)
```

If I use the soup.find_all or set another value at the line Project_title[0] instead of zero, Python shows an error.

I need a list with all the project titles of this Website. Eg.:

- The Superbook: Turn your smartphone into a laptop for $99
- Weights: Weigh Smarter
- Mine Kafon Drone World's First And Only Complete
- Weather Camera System Omega2: $5 IoT Computer with Wi-Fi, Powered by 
  Linux

Comment: Looking at BeautifulSoup's find function, you'll see that it only returns the first element =/

Comment: @Sebastian Fischer, if you have a new question then ask a new question, don't edit code from an answer into your original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()`only returns one element. To get all, you must use `findAll`

Here's the code you need

```
project_elements = soup.findAll('h6', {'class': 'project-title'})
project_titles = [project.findChildren('a')[0].text for project in project_elements]
print(project_titles)
```

We look at all the elements of tag `h6` and class `project-title`. We then take the title from each of these elements, and create a list with it.

Hope it helped, and don't hesitate to ask if you have any question.

edit : the problem of the above code is that it will fail if we do not get at least a child of tag `a` for each element in the list returned by `findAll`

How to prevent this :

```
project_titles = [project.findChildren('a')[0].text for project in project_elements if project.findChildren('a')]
```

this will create the list only if the `project.findChildren('a')` as at least one element. (`if []` returns False)

edit : to get the description of the elements (class `project-blurb`), let's look a bit at the HTML code.

```
<p class="project-blurb">
Bagel is a digital tape measure that helps you measure, organize, and analyze any size measurements in a smart way.
</p>
```

This is only a paragraph of class `project-blurb`. To get them, we could use the same as we did to get the project_elements, or more condensed :

```
project_desc = [description.text for description in soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'project-blurb'})]
```

Comment: Hey HolyDana. Thank you so much!!!!! But I get an error: "IndexError: list index out of range". Do you know why?

Comment: @SebastianFischer this error comes from `project.findChildren('a')[0]`: it fails to find at least a child for one of the elements. I'll edit to add an alternative way to do it, while preventing this error.

Comment: Oh HolyDonna.. Thank you. But it won't work. I only get the result "[]" when I print project_titles

Comment: @SebastianFischer I only realised I forgot to use `findAll` instead of `find`  .... The code should be correct now.

Comment: Hey @HolyDanna.... Thank you. The code works. Now I get a list, seperated with comma and the correct strings. I want to adapt your code to the class "Project-blurb" to get the description of the Proroject. I paste the code in my question on top.... Thank you

Comment: @SebastianFischer look at my edit. You should take a deeper look at the HTML code, as the description does not have the same format as the title.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works and I'm happy right now. Please help me with the next step. I want to scrape the Link (href) from the <h6 class="project-title">. I will paste my (non working) code on top to my quesion  :)

Comment: There is the new question. Please help me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570411/how-to-scrape-href-with-python-3-5-and-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the title of this post i would recommend you two different tutorial based on scraping particular data from a website . They do have a detailed explanation regarding how the task is achieved.

Firstly i would recommend to checkout pyimagesearch
[Scraping images using scrapy.](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/12/scraping-images-with-python-and-scrapy/)

then you should try if you are more specific [web scraping will help you.](https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/)

Answer (score 0):

All the data you want is in the section with the css class *staff-picks*, just find the *h6's* with the *project-title* class and extract the text from the anchor tag inside:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")


print [a.text for a in soup.select("section.staff-picks h6.project-title a")]
```

Output:

```
[u'The Superbook: Turn your smartphone into a laptop for $99', u'Weighitz: Weigh Smarter', u'Omega2: $5 IoT Computer with Wi-Fi, Powered by Linux', u"Bagel: The World's Smartest Tape Measure", u'FireFlies - Truly Wire-Free Earbuds - Music Without Limits!', u'ISOLATE\xae - Switch off your ears!']
```

Or using *find* with *find_all*:

```
project_titles = soup.find("section",class_="staff-picks").find_all("h6", "project-title")
print([proj.a.text for proj in project_titles])
```

There is also only one anchor tag inside each h6 tag so you cannot end up with more than one whatever approach you take.